# Python: Creating map with 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create map data from 2 list data. I have a simple example like below. What I want to do is create 'new_map' data like below. If it contains specific data, the value should be True.

```
all_s = ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4']
data = ['s2', 's4']
new_map = {'s1': False, 's2': True, 's3': False, 's4': True}
```

Are there any smart way (like lambda) to implement this? My python env is 3.X. 
Of course I can resolve this problem if I use for-iter simply. But I wonder there are better ways.

Comment: I can do that! new_map = { s: True if (s in data) else False for s in all_s}

Comment: See the answers below. `True if (s in data) else False` is the same as `s in data` only more verbose.

Comment: Yes I notices your answers are better way. But I wanted to note my solution as my study. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it quickly and efficiently in a pythonic manner:

```
 data_set = set(data)
 new_map = {k: k in data_set for k in all_s}
```

Comment: Arg...beat me by a few seconds. Nice idea to use `set()` too; I didn't think of that! Although, will the function call make it more expensive?

Comment: There is no benefit to using a set if you build the set inside the comprehension :).

Comment: Sorry I got lazy typing on my smart phone and didn't want another line. I'll update.

Comment: Are there any meanings to use set func?

Comment: @jef, `k in data_set` is faster than `k in data` if data is large. It's worth using a set if you need to check a large number of keys and data is reasonably large.

Comment: @David Hoffman Why functions in a list comprehension slow down work?

Answer (score 2):

Try a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
new_map = {i: i in data for i in all_s}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very smart

Comment: @elethan Could you spell me out why boolean types (True or False) are return instead of values?

Comment: @Monica here I am setting the value in each key-value pair to `i in data`. `i in data` == `True` if `i` is a value contained in `data` and `False` otherwise, so all the values end up as either `True` or `False`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @elethan yes, it does! Thank you for your explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a dictionary comprehension:

```
x = {i:True if i in data else False for i in all_s}
```